# Calculating automatically in HTML using javascript on keyup

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to perform a calculation in a PHP app where the user would read data from textboxes and perform a calculation. I tried to calculate using a function that will automatically generate an answer in the 'Bal' textbox which already holds the balance due to pay.

HTML script is below

```
<tr>
<td>Amount   :  <input type='text' name='amount' id='amount' value='1500' /><br><br>
   <td>Old   :  <input type='text' name='old' id='old' value='800' /><br><br>
   <td>New   :  <input type='text' name='new' id='new' value='' /><br><br>
   <td>Bal   :  <input type='text' name='total' id='total' value='700' />
</tr>
```

Using javascript, I came up with the following code but it is not working.

```
$('#amount, #old, #newp').on('input',function() {
    var amount = parseInt($('#amount').val());
    var old = parseFloat($('#old').val());
    var newp = parseFloat($('#newp').val());
    $('#total').val((amount-(old + newp) ? amount-(old + newp) : 0).toFixed(2));
});
```

Below is a snapshot of the HTML file. Please, I need your help.

[image]

If I enter a value on textbox 'New' say 200, the balance needs to be updated to 500, and then on reload, 1000 becomes the old value. I would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Comment: Reload? Are you keeping track of the values between page loads? What is not working exactly?

Comment: The value remains the same when the key is pressed to enter a value in the 'new' textbox.

Comment: "_then on reload_" After a reload everything on the old page is gone, unless you'll set the new values on the server.

Comment: @Teemu, Thanks but please, how do I go about it? I'd appreciate your help.      http://jsfiddle.net/hZ92k/#&togetherjs=EftETtEtDs

Comment: I assume the provided HTML is placed in a form. When you hit ENTER on an input, the form is submitted, and a new page is loaded. The `action` attribute of the form defines the new location. If the attribute is omitted or its value is empty, the current page is loaded. To resolve your problem, we need a bit more information. At first, is there a form? If there is, please add the markup of the form to the question too.

Comment: If you check the javascript code, I have called the id's in the function designed and so key pressed should do the work. I surprised it's not working. I didn't intend to submit it before the balance 'Bal' textbox is calculated. I did mention auto-calculation.

Comment: There's a typo, the `id` in the selectors of `on` context is `newp`, but the element has `new`, the input event is never fired when you're entering new value to `#new`.

Comment: @Teemu, Thanks for spotting that. was very helpful. It's working now but if I use backspace after entering the value, it doesn't update until I refresh the page again. Do you know the reason why?

Comment: The backspace works on the fiddle you've linked, I'm not familiar with jsFiddle's collaboration system, I assume you can see the changes I made to it? Or should I save the changes before you can see them?

Comment: Yeah, Thanks. Just resolved it using ```<?php echo $due?>``` to replace the return to zero. Thanks for the assist.